# MongoDB $facet limitation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, facet

Scenario - For a pipeline the $facet stage has limitation of 16MB data for processing and pass the data to next stage. This means that if I have millions of records (as in my case), the data processed from any $facet stage will be limited to 16MB only.

Question -

1. How to overcome the above problem?
2. Are there any other pipeline stages that can help in this regard?
3. Can we use fix this issue at programming level? (Note: I am using C#'s mongo db driver).

Solutions already looked at :

- Using "allowDiskUse" feature -> This doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Documents cannot exceed 16 MiB, that's a general limitation in MongoDB, it does not apply exclusively for `$facet`. You have to review your data model and/or your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: It is important to understand how you query looks like , to avoid this limitation you probably can split the task in some more queries or add some more restrictive initial project/match stages in the facet pipelines ...

Answer (score 0):

- For facet 104MB pagination limit in mongodb. Per record you can store
  16MB size not more than.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).